# Summing the first n odd numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm new to Haskell -and functional programming altogether- and I wanted to know how would you write such a function in Haskell. I'm used to imperative languages but handling recursion in haskell is elusive to me right now. Note that I know that the sum of odd numbers could be done with n^2 (i.e. sum of the 3 first odd numbers 1 + 3 + 5 = 9 = 3^2) but the idea is to learn recursion with functional programming.

Also, I'm doing this is as part of an algebra workshop and we haven't seen much yet. I need a way to solve it only with recursion.

Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at how `factorial` is presented in the Haskell Wikibook: here:https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Recursion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, you'll need to describe your function.

```haskell
sumFirstOdds :: Int -> Int
```

When you think about recursion, you're going to need a stopping point. In this case, a good stopping point is the sum of the first zero odd numbers, which is zero. You can define your base case like this:

```haskell
sumFirstOdds 0 = 0
```

It's good to get in the habit of declaring the stopping point first when you're writing a recursive function. Otherwise you can easily end up with infinite loops.

Now we need to define what happens when we want to find the sum of the first `n` odd numbers when `n > 0`.

You'll first need to find a way to get the value of the nth odd number: `(n * 2) - 1`.

Now for the recursive portion. It can help you to think about the problem by walking through a few simple examples. If we wanted to get the sum of the first 3 odd numbers, we would use that formula like this:

```haskell
((3 * 2) - 1) + ((2 * 2) - 1) + ((1 * 2) - 1) + 0
  ^               ^               ^             ^
  |               |               |             |
n == 3          n == 2          n == 1        n == 0 (base case)
```

The same algorithm is used starting at the requested number of 3, and adding it to the result of the same algorithm run against 2, then doing the same thing for 1 and again for 0, which is where we hit our base case and stop.

Put into Haskell code, you could write this out as:

```haskell
sumFirstOdds n = ((n * 2) - 1) + (sumFirstOdds (n-1))
```

The calculation is performed against the current `n` value, and that value is added to the result of the same function used against that `n-1` value.

To reiterate what the final function looks like, it is this:

```haskell
sumFirstOdds :: Int -> Int
sumFirstOdds 0 = 0
sumFirstOdds n = ((n * 2) - 1) + (sumFirstOdds (n-1))
```

*Note: this doesn't handle negative input well but I've left that out for the sake of simplicity*

Answer (score 9):

```
-- the odd numbers (all of them!)
[ 1,3.. ]

-- the first N odd numbers:
take n [1,3..]

-- the sum of the first N odd numbers
sum (take n [1,3..])
```

Put it in a function:

```
sumOddNumbers n = sum (take n [1,3..])
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't provide enough context. This is part of an algebra workshop and we haven't seen functions such as take and sum. I need a way to solve it only with recursion. I will edit the question. Thanks for the answer anyway is useful.

Answer (score 2):

Since you should always sum the odd numbers by squaring, I think it would be fun to do *that* by recursion. Since it's silly to do it that way for `Int` or `Integer`, you should work at the type level instead. This is actually just as slow as summing them the naive way, but it's more fun!

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators, GADTs, UndecidableInstances #-}

data Nat = Z | S Nat

infixr 6 :+
type family (:+) (x :: Nat) (y :: Nat) :: Nat where
  'Z :+ n = n
  'S m :+ n = 'S (m :+ n)

infixr 7 :*
type family (:*) (x :: Nat) (y :: Nat) :: Nat where
  'Z :* n = 'Z
  'S m :* n = n :+ m :* n
```

Now to make this usable, you can bring it down to the term level with singletons.

```
data Natty :: Nat -> * where
  Zy :: Natty 'Z
  Sy :: Natty n -> Natty ('S n)

plus :: Natty m -> Natty n -> Natty (m :+ n)
plus Zy n = n
plus (Sy m) n = Sy (plus m n)

times :: Natty m -> Natty n -> Natty (m :* n)
times Zy _ = Zy
times (Sy m) n = n `plus` (m `times` n)

square :: Natty n -> Natty (n :* n)
square n = times n n
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is not needed, but in general you can use an accumulator for recursive computations in a helper function.

```
sumodds n = go n 0
   where go 0 a = a
         go k a = go (k-1) (a + 2*k-1)

> map sumodds [0..9]
[0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81]
```